# Adjective for the shape of a spiral?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

In English, the adjective *circular* is used for a circle, and the adjective *elliptical* for an ellipse.

Similarly, the adjective *helical* is used for a helix, but a helix is 3-dimensional.

What is the corresponding adjective for a **spiral**?

Answer (score 4):

The word *spiral* is in fact an adjective, as cited in the Cambridge English dictionary.  It so happens that it can also be used as a noun and a verb,

Comment: From your feedback, I have rephrased the question to find precedents in formal writing. Please have a look. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606072/how-do-i-express-in-the-shape-of-a-spiral-as-adjective-in-an-acceptable-way-p

Comment: I don’t know exactly how things work around here, but you asked twice (don’t do that), had different answers at both, had both questions variously closed and reopened, and here we are: [*Spiral* is the adjective you’re looking for](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606072/how-do-i-express-in-the-shape-of-a-spiral-as-adjective-in-an-acceptable-way-p/606080#606080). Kinda *circular*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat, your confusion is indeed due to the quick closing, then re-opening, of this original question. The closure was not due to a previous question or answer here. When this question was closed, I realized I would not get answers to it, so I asked instead for an expression suitable for use in formal writing.